# Is there a way to make a light weight ajax call in Joomla?

Tags: ajax

I want to make a lightweight ajax call in Joomla ( all I need is basically a php script that makes a curl call). Currently, we're doing this in components controller tasks (com_home, com_widgit, etc).

This is causing a lot of unneeded overhead by loading Joomla. Performance testing shows that a plain php script with a curl call is order of magnitudes faster than using the joomla controller.

I've looked into the com_ajax but from what I can tell its not what I'm looking for since I'm the component developer:
http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

```
If you are a component developer, you do not need to use com_ajax to implement Ajax functionality in it. You can do so directly in your component.
```

I also have access to the server and can make ajax calls outside of Joomla, but since that seems like a hack I'd rather use Joomla, if possible.

Is there a way to make a lightweight ajax call in joomla?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to make an AJAX call in component?](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component)

Comment: There are some great answers to this at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component

Comment: While somewhat similar, I think that this question asks what is the lightest weight method instead of the "proper" way to do an AJAX call. I am interested to see if anyone can speak to the performance level of the ajax calls, over just how to make one.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in the lightweightest way to call your component, since you are executing inside Joomla, you have to wait until the CMS is initialized. (If not, thn you are looking for an external script)

- Following all the available core events, you can create a plugin to answer the call and stop the rest of the execution. For instance, **onAfterInitialise**
- You can also, execute in any of the following events, e.g. **onAfterRoute** http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events
- As you are the component developer, you can install a create a plugin and install a plgAjaxYxxxx
- If you want to keep it inside the component, and avoid plugins, then you can return the response inside the main **component** php script, in the internal  **dispatcher**, or as a **task** in a **controller**.

In my experience, I prefer to implement it as a task in the controller. In this way, all business reponsabilities are in a single place. Beyond the extra load, it is easier to mantain.