# How to retrieve data from the Joomla DB via jQuery.ajax without controller

Tags: development, joomla-api, virtuemart, database, ajax

I need to retrieve some data from **#__virtuemart_order_histories** in **templates/active_tmpl/html/com_virtuemart/orders/details_history.php** via jQuery.ajax. I know that I can do it with a new &task= in controller but is it possible to make the ajax query to the DB in the above file without touching Virtuemart core files?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate for your link contents the answer WITH changes in controller and other core files but I need a solution WITHOUT touching them

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it whenever you are allowed to.

Comment: Do you have a custom component or plugin you could leverage with server side PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following simple solution: to add in **.../orders/details_history.php** the script:

```
var response = jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",   
  url: "index.php?tmpl=raw&order_id=<?php echo $this->orderdetails['details']['BT']->virtuemart_order_id; ?>",   
  async: false
}).responseText;
alert(response);
```

and to create the file **raw.php** in the folder of active template with the query to the DB:

```
$order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
...
```

Any other better solution will be appreciated

Comment: Please check another answer for a similar solution but that would be better in terms of good practices and not making you template dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a plugin and use the [com_ajax](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) extension for it.
Please never, ever use $_REQUEST to receive any data from request. Especially if you are going to use the data for database requests. 
Please use the [JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) object for this.

Comment: Thanks, but I've found the simpler way: `JRequest::getVar('order_id')`

Comment: @stckvrw - `JRequest` is deprecated. Please use [JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a view, in my case named "ajax". All you need to do is create a directory 'ajax' in the view directory. Inside this dir put in the view.html.php containing the display class:

```
public function display($tpl = null)    {
        //Get post data
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        //do whatever you want to to

        echo json_encode($returnData);
        exit;
    }
}
```

It is important to set the exit; command, which prevents getting template html inside your request.

Inside your jQuery script, call this view with post data like this:

```
var post_vars = new Array();
post_vars.push({name:'somevar', value:'somevalue'});

var data = jQuery.post('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=ajax', post_vars);
data.done(function(reply_data) {
  var response_json = jQuery.parseJSON(reply_data);
  //do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Not the clearest and not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the clearest solution for this situation would be:

adding `&format=json` to your query, and point it to whatever view you would like

```
var response = jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",   
  url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=order&order_id=<?php echo $this->orderdetails['details']['BT']->virtuemart_order_id; ?>&format=json"
});
```

Then you need to add `view.json.php` at `components/com_virtuemart/view/order/`
and do whatever you need at `display()` function.