# How do I migrate AJAX interface from 1.5 to 3.x for mobile App

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, joomla-api, ajax, joomla-1.5

I'm updating a website selling online services that has a complimentary App acting as a mobile front end to the Joomla v1.5 CMS.
The App communicates via a component (com_mobile) using JSON data exchanges.
The URL's are typically of the type:

```
index.php?option=com_mobile&view=public&task=all&format=raw
```

Researching the latest v3.4 Joomla I find that format=raw has been dropped and there is now a Joomla Ajax Interface (com_ajax) component.
Nice, but I don't want to break the usability of the nearly 100,000 mobile installations already using the (soon to be legacy) v1.5 url format.

Is there a way to re-introduce the "format=raw" option into the latest version of Joomla? Other suggestions welcome (url rewrite?) ?

Comment: Try looking at following: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component

Comment: Yes I had found that question. It's a year old now and I wanted to check if there had been further developments in Joomla >3.3 that should be taken into consideration. It's a bit of a hack. I was hoping to find something that was future proof so I don't have to revisit it again with a next major release.

Comment: What are you talking about that format=raw has been dropped? I have no knowledge about it and last time I tested it was working just fine. Please add a link to an official document stating the removal of this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd close this one off with what I ended up doing to solve my migration process.
In the end I bought a copy of ***jbackend*** which you can find in joomla extensions directory which is a plugin solution with component support making it very flexible and customisable.
Can't recommend it enough. It's been running on my site for a few years now and the App has about 30k monthly users which it supports without problems.