# Joomla AJAX request

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, mvc

I'm developing a Joomla component where I have a treeview in the sidebar with the content of a database table. When clicking a node of this sidebar I want to show the children nodes in the main part of the window as a list (as the windows explorer does). For what I have been reading the best way to do this is an ajax request like explained [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component).

I link to the url in each node: `href="index.php?option=com_nautilus&task=datalist&format=raw"`

In controller.php I add:

> Blockquote

```
public function datalist()
{   
    $this->input->set('view', 'Datalist');

    parent::display();
}
```

I create /views/datalist with the file view.raw.php

> Blockquote

```
<?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

    class SimilarViewDatalist extends JViewLegacy
    {
        function display($tpl = null)
        {
            parent::display($tpl);
        }
    }
```

and /views/datalist/tmpl with the file default.php

> Blockquote

```
   <?php

           echo "Hello World from /views/datalist/tmpl/default.php";
```

But I get:

An error has occurred.
 500 View class not found [class, file]: nautilusViewDatalist, C:\xampp\apps\joomla\htdocs\administrator\components\com_nautilus\views\dataList\view.raw.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component's name is com_nautilus. With Joomla MVC your controller is looking for a class called "**nautilus**ViewDatalist" in the file view.raw.php but you named your class "SimilarViewDatalist". That's were the error 500 comes from.

Answer (score 2):

How to Implement Ajax in Joomla Component

Create Controller File Where you will send ajax request from javascript to PHP

controller.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Access Deny');
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
class OpenChatController extends JController
{

    function saveChatViaAjax()
    {
        $app=JFactory::getApplication();
        $jinput=$app->input;
        $res=array();
        //Implement Your Logic i am giving some sample response
        $res['status']=true;
        $res['msg']=$jinput->get('msg');
        echo json_encode($res);
        $app->close();
    }


}
```

From View Page You will send Ajax request using Jquery(also you can use native javascript xhr)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
        //Sending Ajax Request to saveChatViaAjax method on Controller OpenChatController
        var param={};
        param.option='com_openchat';
        param.task='saveChatViaAjax';
        param.msg='Please save this mesage';

        $.post('index.php',param,function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
});
</script>
```

For more info You can download https://f10df5600a7c9a74bb22e6b8df498775b8acd045.googledrive.com/host/0Bwk7CPC93wgSVjZUR2c2enNnZ3M/Source%20Codes/Joomla%20OpenChat%20V1.0.0%20Source%20Code/com_openchat-v1.0.0.zip

You can watch whole video series
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7kkxuLFYIDOrj395REpd0golrCV7XLcY