# Run function in com_content with ajax - doesn't call it correctly

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, ajax

I've been following this tutorial to make an AJAX login form: 
http://www.mysite4u.net/joomla-articles/jquery-ajax-joomla-login.html

But I can't get it to work. The ajax call doesn't work. It gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of null

I tried reading this documentation, but I guess that it is not the AJAX component that is used in this, and it doesn't mention anything about calling components: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

This is my AJAX call:

```
form = jQuery('#userForm'); 

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_content&format=ajax&view=article&task=loginUser&tmpl=component',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        form: jQuery(form).serializeArray()
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        if ( result.loggedIn == 1 ) {                   
            //User logged in                    
        }
        else {                  
            //User not logged in                    
        }               
    }
});
```

And the function inside `components/com_content/views/article/view.ajax.php` ("view.ajax.php" is a file I've created):

```
public function _logInUser( $form ){
    $options = array();
    $credentials = array();

    $credentials['username'] = $form[0]['value'];
    $credentials['password'] = $form[1]['value'];

    $result = JFactory::getApplication()->login($credentials, $options);        
    $result = ($result) ? 1 : 0;

    //1     - logged in
    //0     - not logged in     
    echo json_encode( array('loggedIn' => $result) );                   
    jexit();
}
```

Comment: to JonasB: No, the tutorial mentioned contains THE IMPORTANT PART. Please go trough the tutorial more carefully. Unfortunately It was you who missed the part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apperently I was missing an important part. I needed to have the "loginUser" `task` addded to the switch in `view.ajax.php` like:

```
function display($tpl = null)
{       
    $task = JRequest::getString('task');        
    switch( $task ){                        
        case "registerNewUser":         
            $this->_registerNewUser( JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('form', NULL, 'ARRAY') );             
            break;
        case "loginUser":           
            $this->_logInUser( JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('form', NULL, 'ARRAY') );               
            break;
    }       
    jexit();                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand you in your question but in the directory of com_content/views/article you cannot/should not create a **view.html.php** file since it originally has a good view.html.php file.

In the tutorial which you follow the author says that you should create an **'view.ajax.php'** file in com_content/views/article folder (not a view.html.php file). Maybe that is causing your problem since you created a wrong file for this ajax call.

And if that is just a mistake in your question, then you also might want to study this earlier answer about ajax calls within Joomla here (it is better not to repeat that here):
[What is the proper way to make an AJAX call in component?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component)

Comment: Woops, my fault... It is a `view.ajax.php` I've created. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I added a link in my answer about the proper ajax calls in Joomla, if you did not study that before.