# Simple AJAX call to a component giving 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: component, ajax

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Joomla and web-development, so I probably am making a dumb beginner mistake. So far I've worked through much of the [MVC tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component) in the Joomla documentation, and I've read answers to the [What is the proper way to make an AJAX call in component?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component) question, but I'm still having trouble.

I am modifying an existing component (J2Store) so I'm not using com_ajax. I want a JavaScript script to be able to use a method in a subcontroller (com_j2store/controllers/products.php) to retrieve data. In my subcontroller class I have a dummy method for testing this out:

**site/components/com_j2store/controllers/products.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package J2Store
 * @copyright Copyright (c)2014-17 Ramesh Elamathi / J2Store.org
 * @license GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
// No direct access to this file
use Joomla\Registry\Format\Json;

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/controllers/productbase.php');
class J2StoreControllerProducts extends J2StoreControllerProductsBase
{
...

  // My method
  public function doSomething(){
    echo "something";
  }

}
```

Based on what I've read I cobbled together the following AJAX call:

**site/templates/my_template/js/user.js**

```
// menu select options

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ...

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "index.php?option=com_j2store&format=raw&task=products.doSomething", 
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){ 
      alert(response); 
    }
  });

  ...
}
```

(This is a project I inherited and the previous developer made the choice to create and put code in the user.js template file. I am putting my code in this file as well because I'm modifying what he did.)

What I expect to happen when I trigger the AJAX call is an alert window popping up and saying "something". However when the AJAX call is triggered the console logs a 403 (Forbidden) error, and the line number it gives is indeed the line number of the AJAX call.

Because of my inexperience and how many different aspects are involved in this problem it's hard for me to know what's causing the issue. In particular I don't know if I've structured my code incorrectly in the Joomla structure or if my AJAX call is just wrong. Hopefully someone can help clarify things for me.

**update** mixahlos pointed out that my old url "index.php?option=com_j2store&format=raw&controller=products&task=doSomething" was incorrect, but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just begin to develop a joomla component you really got into a heavy duty job right away. J2Store is a quite well built component (I like that and use that), however it's built with using FOF (and on the top of that, with the old FOF and by a quite advanced developer guy). So you will have few additional things to study and a bit of a headache too (chronic :) ).

I did not yet test the following but as far as I know this component, try to create your ajax call url like this:

```
url: 'index.php?option=com_j2store&view=products&task=doSomething',
```

This should make the required call to the targeted J2Store controller function according to me, even if it does not look like that. Give me some feedback.

... still testing the calls on local host...

**If you run your Joomla** on localhost, then it's better to use the url in the call with opening backslash, like:

```
url: '/index.php?option=com_j2store&view=callback&task=callback&method=doSomething',
```

First, it is not a bad idea to place and test your **doSomething()** function inside the **J2Store callback controller** class (callback.php) since this component is using this class mostly for ajax calls as I see. You will find this class among the component controllers.

```
class J2StoreControllerCallback extends F0FController
{
}
```

If I call a function here in this class with the above url, then I got **200 OK** response. And as I see, in this class, the csrf protection is also turned off which can help you with successful ajax calls too. Interesting things...

So I put the following ajax call script in the **components/com_j2store/templates/default/default.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $ = jQuery.noConflict();        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#mybutton2').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/index.php?option=com_j2store&view=callback&task=callback&method=doSomething',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',                        
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('its good');
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        console.log('its not working');
                    },
                });
            });
        });

</script>
```

I just also placed a button in this same template file (in the top div somewhere) for testing the ajax call:

```
<div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="mybutton2">MyButton</button>
</div>
```

The above template is the main product list template of the shop. So the ajax call gets through here, however many test should be done still, from where and to which class the ajax calls should be made to and a few of the other things... I just hope you can follow this.

Now, just to really close this question, we have **a successful ajax call** to one of the J2Store controller(callback.php) which is immediately checking the call and redirecting the call to the **Model(components/com_j2store/models/callback.php)**, which Model receives the call and check if it has any **$method** corresponding, defined in this class, same as in the method defined in the ajax call. So I placed our **doSomething() function** in the bottom of this callback model class (models/callback.php):

```
function doSomething() 
{
        $mymessage = 'this is from the callback function';
        echo new JResponseJson($mymessage);
        $status = true;
        return $status;
}
```

And in this callback model Class's function:**function runCallback($method){}** I inserted a 3 liner **if checking** at line 23, which looks like this:

```
if ($rawDataGet['method'] == 'doSomething')
{
    $this->doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

And now **my doSomething()** function is running and I get whatever response I define in my doSomething() function. So this is how ajax calls should work within an MVC which is structured this way with FOF.

Comment: Thanks Zollie, I tried your url but I'm still getting the same error. Some other discussions I looked at mentioned that doing AJAX calls on localhost can be weird and I am on localhost, could that be the issue?

I'm also looking at the J2Store developer documentation but it's pretty sparse.

Comment: No, the additional problem I see that in order to make a successful ajax call to a specific component function, you have to make the call from inside that particular component. in Joomla you cannot make just ajax calls from everywhere this way. That would be a relatively high security problem in Joomla if it was that way. So what i can spot out in your try is that you try to start this call from a wrong place. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: As I checked it further, yes, the local host is also causing problems for this call.

Comment: Ok, I can move my code into the j2store component code to see if that fixes it. Do you know what I can do to let me test it on localhost?

Comment: @you - I made a short update in my answer regarding this ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I moved my doSomething() method into /my_site/com_j2store/controllers/callback.php and moved my ajax call to /my_site/media/j2store/js/j2store.js with your new url, and the ajax call is being triggered as expected but now I'm get a 404 (Not Found) error instead. Is this because there's no corresponding "callback" folder in the views folder?

Comment: Actually without that view defined, the ajax call still should reach the controller function. In your browser console you have to check the request and response url, if there is any problem with that. So the url called is really the url what you want? for me this exact ajax call give 200 OK response. However then the response is FAILED at the moment.

Comment: So actually I got a response from this class if I call my doSomething() function, but interestingly i got a response from another function in this Class. There is a function called read() in this class and I got a response from that, whatever I define in that function. So if I make this ajax call to this callback Class, then I got the success response now from the read() function, despite I call the doSomething() function in my ajax call.

Comment: I put a sample code in my answer for you which is getting response from the read() function from this class which you can also find in this class.

Comment: I sorted out my 404 problem with the url, I just have multiple sites on my localhost so I had to do "/my_site/index.php?..." but I'm getting the "FAILED" response for the reasons you describe. I guess when the callback.php controller is given a task it calls execute($task), which then calls $this->read() which then returns "FAILED". I tried to change the body of the execute($task) function to be "$this->doSomething();" but that returns a 403 error again, which I find extremely strange because it's just an object calling one of its own (public) methods.

Comment: the 'FAILED' text is actually defined in the callback Class read() function at line 39 in callback.php file, find it and write it over instead of FAILED, write there 'GOOD DOG' and you will get that text as a response. So your ajax call is actually not failed at all. It is a successful ajax call. now. :)

Comment: This class is actually getting data from the j2Store database originally, but this is just a good place to test your ajax calls first, then you will move on your road to many more of your ajax calls as you will move with your projects and understanding more the whole structure of J2store classes and functions.

Comment: This solves my original problem of "I'm getting a 403 error" but I guess I still don't see how to actually access my doSomething() method, since the callback controller is just calling its execute($task) function and seems to ignore doSomething() entirely. Is this something that needs to be handled by the runCallback($method) function in the callback model?

Comment: Yes, if I make the call within this class then I would also do something like you think about now. But check over the other possibility that with copying this callback class a bit you can now start to think about and make your own controller class within J2store for yourself and you can start to structure your own class where you can handle your ajax calls. But this is just an idea among the lot of possibilities. Or you can also create a plugin extending the J2store classes, there are too many possibilities...

Comment: Ok, I'll work at it and see what I can figure out. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I wish you good time with the development! As an additional info, this controller class is redirecting all of the incoming calls to the model (as the controller should do it's job actually), then your doSomething() function has to be in the model class: callback.php. In the ajax call, the $method should be explicitly defined for the controller. Also in other situations the controller can redirect your ajax call to a view not only to a model, so this is how the MVC structure works (but as I wrote, J2Store is a FOF MVC design framework within Joomla, with very helpful classes and functions.

Comment: @you - I finalized my answer with running your doSomething() function from the Model(callback). Just to really close this question well.

Comment: Your added explanation really helped me a lot to learn how to access my custom methods, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the url in your Ajax call is wrong.
You shouldn't use the controller as a var in the url but as prefix followed by the task. Also after the "?" goes the option and then the rest of url vars.

Try to Replace :

> url:
>   "index.php?format=raw&option=com_j2store&controller=products&task=doSomething",

With

```
url: "index.php?option=com_j2store&format=raw&task=products.doSomething",
```

Comment: I tried your url and I'm getting the same result as before, but thanks still for correcting that. I'll change the url in my question so it's more correct.